# WCAG 3.2.2 On Input and toggle switch on a website

Tags: web, wcag

I've read WCAG and other sources that deal with interpretation and am still a bit confused if I will have to breach 3.2.2 or not with following. Maybe you have some extra thoughts:

1. a toggle switch on a page will be used to basically reset a table with selected rows
2. toggle is default "on" and shows "best combination"
3. if user selects different rows the toggle switch changes to "off" state and user is informed that "changes were made"

Update: number of rows is between 1 and max. 30, most users will have 5 or something. Rows include financial info, so you get a final amount based on rows you have chosen (or were pre-selected for you). We have not specified that states would be saved but that is a good idea - toggling can then swap user selection with default selection. My suggestion to the designer was to use a (reset) button, but they will have the toggle... This is only the first step - you have to confirm the choices before submission.

Toggle's state is also dynamically changed - if user does not change selection of rows it remains on default, if user makes a change it is toggled...

So my dilemma is - is this change of context or not?

If a toggle switch is toggled again, then default rows are selected and user is again informed.

Personally I think this is dangerous and I've suggested a confirmation dialog or maybe a submit button so that user confirms the change before it happens.

But when reading Understanding SC 3.2.2 (https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/consistent-behavior-unpredictable-change.html) I may be mistaken and it is totally fine if toggle switch changes row selection at once and user is informed about it (visually we change the text besides the toggle and screen-reader users will be notified by status message that is visually hidden (role="status")).

What do you think - is it ok if toggle "resets" the not-default row selection or should we have a "confirmation" (confirm dialog / submit button)?

Concept gif:

[Animated gif showing toggle button changing dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JK7en.gif)

Comment: If a user decides to toggle it off once again after selecting some options does it remember what they selected or does it forget all of their changes? Also how many rows of data are we talking here, 10, 100, 1000? I think I know the answer (it resets everything each time it is toggled) but I just wanted to check as it isn't 100% clear. Also why does it exist, context is important. I am 99% certain this should be a `<button>` with "reset choices to default" or similar as the text but depending on number of rows and whether it actually toggles I can't be 100%. We can discuss WCAG after that.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie - added an update, hope it can clarify the situation a bit. I was suggesting reset button but they insist with toggle...

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to directly address SC 3.2.2 as it is to do with things like changing a drop-down and the page changing etc. If you click a toggle / checkbox then you are expecting something to change, so it should be fine (always difficult to be 100% without an actual code example but 95% sure).

However we are "flying close" to other guidance such as [SC 3.3.6 - Error prevention All](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/minimize-error-reversible-all.html). However yet again you pass this as this is before submission, but it does hint to an issue that needs addressing.

What if a user accidentally presses the toggle before submission? You alluded to this in your question as something you had already thought of!

Obviously if there is a confirmation screen and a way to reverse their submission if they accidentally reset their data, then it isn't a problem as per WCAG, but what an awful user experience **for everybody**.

So the short answer is the solution probably (almost certainly) "passes" WCAG, but let's try and take it from "minimum requirements" to "great experience" for assistive technology and other users alike!

### 1. Save the "state" before toggling

As suggested in the comments and now within your question, saving the state before toggling would be the best option.

That way if I selected 10 options out of the list and then toggled to "data set 1" (default) I can still get my options back by simply toggling back to "data set 2" (my choices).

By being able to reverse it, mistakes are easily avoided and it should be super simple to implement.

**Personally I think this is the best way.**

A couple of things to consider:-

- Make sure the toggle checkbox makes sense to everyone. I would probably suggest **2 radio buttons** are more appropriate, one named "default options" and one named "your choices" or "user selected options" etc. This makes more sense than a checkbox, which would be difficult to name in a way that makes it obvious that you can toggle between two states.
- Make sure you have an `aria-live` region or similar mechanism to let screen reader users know that their selected options have changed. I would probably add "you can switch back to your selections by choosing 'you choices'" or something similar as part of this notification so people are aware this is a reversible process.

### 2. Make it a "restore defaults" `<button>`.

It makes no sense to have a checkbox here, people know if they changed an option so they know if the defaults are showing.

Similarly I like to think of checkboxes as "yes / no" answers. I cannot think what question / statement we could make that makes sense in a "yes / no" fashion.

As such a "restore defaults" `<button>` makes a lot more sense, assuming the action is not reversible.

This means you should definitely have a confirmation modal pop up to avoid accidental wiping of user selections. (as you stated)

For example: "Restore Defaults" -> "Are you sure, your selections will be lost." -> "Yes restore the defaults" or "no keep my selections".

Comment: thanks for this elaboration! I will suggest and implement the user choices, that is a fantastic idea, and screen-reader users will be informed about the change when toggling. Was suspecting that toggling context will be in violation of 3.2.2 but looks like I've been to idealistic when thinking about it. Regarding error evaluation, there are no errors possible - user either accepts default or changes rows and submits, so I just have to make it clear "you are submitting your own rows / suggested rows" I think. Personally I would go for "restore defaults button" but UX persists..

Comment: Don't have enough reputation to accept your answer, but will do it in the future